# get a batch file to tell me how many line are in a csv file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch file that I am using for a toad automation. the batch file should be simple enough but it isn't liking the if statuement for some off reason I even tried the GTR example but sadly nothing all I get on the if statement is that the syntax is incorrect and do not know why.

```
    @Echo off
    Set _File=ExportDiffFile.csv
    Set /a _Lines=0
    For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< %_File%') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
    REM Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines.

    if "%_Lines%"=="1"(
        Echo %_File% has no new lines.
        Echo 100.
        REM exit 100
    )
    else
    (
        Echo %_File% has %_Lines% new lines.
        Echo adding into the server.
        REM exit 0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I didn't have it set correctly.

here is how it should of been. Leaving the question here in case someone needs it.

```
    @Echo off
    Set _File=ExportDiffFile.csv
    Set /a _Lines=0
    For /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< %_File%') Do Set /a _Lines=%%j
    Echo %_File% has %_Lines% lines.


    IF "%_Lines%" EQU "1" (
        Echo %_File% has no new lines.
        Echo 100.
        REM exit 100
    ) ELSE (
        Echo %_File% has %_Lines% new lines.
        Echo adding into the server.
        REM exit 0
    )
```

Comment: Yep. It is pretty clear in the help file what the proper syntax is for an IF ELSE command.